# How to change Toggle element's label if on/off in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Trying to figure out how to change Unity's Toggle element's label text depending on if its on or off.

```
if(Toggle.isOn) {
    this.text = "Toggle is on"
} else {
    this.text = "Toggle is off"
}
```

Comment: Looks good buddy

Comment: @Maakep But whats the code to change the text? `this.text = "..."` doesn't seem right

Comment: If you're on an object that has a text component: `GetComponent<Text>().text = "Toggle is on";`

Comment: @Maakep I don't think the toggle does since its called "Label"

Answer (score 5):

You have to set a function for the On Value Changed event in Unity.

1. Add a function to one of your scripts.
2. Add the object with your script to the On Value Changed field in your Toggle Object.
3. Set the function to call
4. Add the Parameters
   [image: On Value Changed field in your toggle object]

copy your code into the function that gets called:

```
public void valueChanged(Toggle t)
    {
        if (t.isOn) {
            t.GetComponentInChildren<Text> ().text = "Toggle is on";
        } else {
            t.GetComponentInChildren<Text> ().text = "Toggle is off";
        }
    }
```

Comment: But whats the code to change the text? `this.text = "..."` doesn't seem right

Comment: I updated the answer. To get the Text component of a Toggle you have to call .GetComponentInChildren<Text>()

Comment: Yeah buddy! Thanks mate!